# Streaming video from AWS

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, video, amazon-s3

try to streaming video from my Amazon Cloudfront. I have created a bucket with html page (jwplayer.html), video (process.mp4) and jwplayer (uploaded from official website). Also I create a CloudFront web distribution and CloudFront RTMP distribution.

Add to jwplayer.html next code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Amazon CloudFront Streaming with JW Player 6</TITLE>


    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://d7io7dti9fwp9.cloudfront.net/video/jwplayer-7.2.4/jwplayer.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key = "AHKJ8oqvx6qWX8d9RY00tDP7VTETGz814NNzLw==";</script>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
    <H1>This video is streamed by CloudFront and played by JW Player 6.</H1>



    <div id='mediaplayer'></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
   jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
       file: "rtmp://s2z3jy56jskpuw.cloudfront.net/cfx/st/mp4:process.mp4",
      width: "720",
      height: "480"
   });
    </script>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Here is my result:

http://d7io7dti9fwp9.cloudfront.net/jwplayer.html

This solution does not work in my browser.

Comment: I am currently having the same issue it seems, where you able to come to a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are taking help from this tutorial
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/TutorialStreamingJWPlayer.html

They have explained everything. there might be file permission issues.
Take a look there once.

Thanks